# notify_all does not wake up wait thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

```
DBThread::DBThread() : running_(false)
{

}

DBThread::~DBThread()
{
    if (thread_)
    {
        thread_->join();
    }
}

void DBThread::Init()
{
    thread_ = std::make_shared<std::thread>(std::bind(&DBThread::Run, this));
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    cv_.wait(lock, [&] {return running_; });
    std::cout << "Init success";
}

void DBThread::AddTask(std::shared_ptr<Delegate> task)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    task_queue_.push(task);
}

void DBThread::Run()
{
    running_ = true;
    cv_.notify_all();
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        cv_.wait(lock, [&] {return !task_queue_.empty(); });
        std::cout << "run task" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I have two threads,let's name it A and B,A call Init and wait for B to fully initialized, A sometimes hang on wait even if running_ is true.Any idea why this happens.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What type is `running_`? `bool` or `std::atomic<bool>`?

Comment: running_ is purely bool,I have tried declare it as std::atomic<bool>,still not work

Comment: @user2260241 Nothing is guaranteed to be atomic by default in C++, not even `bool`. You _must_ synchronize access to `running_` or you will have a data race.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::condition_variable::wait(lock, pred)` is basically the same as

```
while (!pred()) {
    wait(lock);
}
```

If the thread sets `running_` to `true` and calls `notify_all()` between the time that the predicate is checked, but before wait is called, then the notification will be lost, and the wait will wait until another notification comes. Easiest way to fix it is:

```
void DBThread::Run()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    running_ = true;
    cv_.notify_all();
    while (true)
    {
        cv_.wait(lock, [&] {return !task_queue_.empty(); });
        std::cout << "run task" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,bro.I figured it out,Like you said,it has a timing between the predicate is checked but before wait is called.